# Кодирование строки в переменной

Tags: c#

Как закодировать строку в Base64? Пробовал такой код, но он не подошел

```
public static string ftppath = "ZnRwOi8vMTI3LjAuMC4xOjIxLw=="; //ftp://127.0.0.1/
public static string toParse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(ftppath));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743160/how-do-i-encode-and-decode-a-base64-string

Comment: А зачем вы это делаете из константы в статических полях, не проще ли сразу в открытом виде присвоить константу?

Comment: Мне нужно что бы в программе не было открытых данных сервера

Comment: Base64 - это вполне себе открытые данные.

Comment: `public static string ftppath` замените на `public const string ftppath` и заработает.

Comment: А вообще, проследить к какому адресу обращается ваше приложение можно вообще без реверс-инжиниринга, достаточно просто сдампить трафик приложения, делов - несколько минут. Данные, захардкоженые в приложении, не подлежат защите. Опять же вы раскодируете строку в поле `toParse`, ни что не мешает посмотреть его содержимое во время работы приложения. В общем, так себе "защита".